# Parsing a json file in JAVA

Tags: java, android, json

I have json file. Now, a field names `"refs"` isn't available in every array. So, what is procedure to parse this kind of field. Because, when I try to parse the json file, 1st array don't have `"refs"` field but 2nd array hasn't. That's why it throw Null Pointer exception. I tried with this code

```
 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(tokener);

 for (int index = 0; index < jsonArray.length(); index++) {

       JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(index);

          if(!jsonObject.getString("refs").equalsIgnoreCase(null)){
                String refs = jsonObject.getString("refs");
                    }
        }
```

But, it's not working. What is the way to handle this situation or what is the way to solve that problem. Thank you.

Comment: Try this tutorial and follow each step http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: can you give your json response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not sure that the key is present, call [has](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) to check first.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is in your if statement....

```
if(!jsonObject.getString("refs").equalsIgnoreCase(null)){
```

What you should be writing is:

```
if(!jsonObject.has("refs")){
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(jsonObject.has("refs")){

  refs = jsonObject.getString("refs");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by just replacing 'if' condition like this, It works for me hope useful to u also.

```
if(jObj.optString("refs") != null)
```